# Why won't jsontool parse my array?

Tags: json, bash

I'm having trouble parsing this json, which contains an array as its outermost element:

```
response=[ { "__type": "File", "name": "...tfss-ea51ec70-d3a8-45e5-abbf-294f2c2c81f0-myPicture.jpg", "url": "http://files.parse.com/ac3f079b-cacb-49e9-bd74-8325f993f308/...tfss-ea51ec70-d3a8-45e5-abbf-294f2c2c81f0-myPicture.jpg" } ]

for blob in $response
do
    url=$(echo $blob | json url)
done
```

But this last [json](http://mike.bailey.net.au/2011/02/json-from-the-command-line/) parsing gives a bunch of errors:

```
json: error: input is not JSON: Bad object at line 2, column 1:

    ^
```

Do I need to do something special to turn a JSON array into a bash array, or vice versa?

Comment: Please provide a runnable example that demonstrates your error.

Comment: Is that the string that you're actually injecting to the json tool? Perhaps show the code that generates the response?

Comment: @chepner edited, should be standalone runnable now and produces the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should quote the value of `reponse` to protect it from the shell trying to interpret it:

```
response='[ { "__type": "File", "name": "...tfss-ea51ec70-d3a8-45e5-abbf-294f2c2c81f0-myPicture.jpg", "url": "http://files.parse.com/ac3f079b-cacb-49e9-bd74-8325f993f308/...tfss-ea51ec70-d3a8-45e5-abbf-294f2c2c81f0-myPicture.jpg" } ]'
```

And you can't expect the shell to be able to parse JSON, so `for blob in $response` isn't going to work out. According to http://trentm.com/json/, using `-a` should handle the array:

```
while read url ; do
   # use $url here...
done < <(echo "$response" | json -a url)
```

Answer (score 0):

After putting your json in a file and piping it through jsontool it works just fine, so I'm guessing your file has some weird whitespace which is breaking in jsontool.

Try this instead:

```
cat your_file.json | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' | json
```

Comment: Of course, a proper JSON parser should ignore whitespace.